# Rails: Pin selectize from cdnjs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selectize.js, import-maps

Am trying to pin the selectize script (https://selectize.dev) for my rails 7 app (select2 simply seems too complicated), according to their webpage, they are on cdnjs. But when I issue the following command:

```
bin/importmap pin selectize --from=cdnjs
```

I get:

```
Couldn't find any packages in ["selectize"] on cdnjs
```

How do I make cdnjs "known" to importmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to write like below to terminal.

```
./bin/importmap pin selectize --from jsdelivr
```

Comment: thanks that worked. I have however switched to jsbundling in the meantime. I found importmaps too much of a hassle.